# Von Neumann algebras as complemented subspaces

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

> **Question:** Does there exist a non-injective von Neumann algebra $M\subseteq B(H)$, which is a complemented Banach subspace of $B(H)$?

According to an [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135759/on-complemented-von-neumann-algebras), this problem was still open as of 2013. I'm curious about the current status of this problem. Thank you in advance.